# How do I use setIterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, setinterval

I am having trouble with setInterval.  When I run the following code, `setMilliseconds(milliseconds - 100);` seems only to run once.  Say `milliseconds` starts at 100, the console log just shows `900' in an infinite loop.

```
timer = setInterval(() => {
  setMilliseconds(milliseconds - 100);
  console.log(milliseconds);

  if (milliseconds <= 0) {
    console.log("stopped");
    clearInterval(timer);
    pause();
  }
}, 100);
```

`setMilliseconds` id defined above the code as `const [milliseconds, setMilliseconds] = useState(0);`

I almost never use setIterval.  I a doing somithing wrong?

Here is the full file:
https://gist.github.com/timscodebase/86fd0951a30b150b438a04a3fd5ec4c1

Comment: There are subtleties to using `setInterval` with the `useState` hook. The answers to the question linked above go over those and provide alternatives and guidance.

Comment: This is why so many devs hate Stackoverflow!!!

Comment: ...Because they get pointed to answers to their questions? Because it is as simple as [edit]ing their question to explain *why* a duplicate question does not answer their question, as mentioned in [the online help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) and [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252252/215552), to get it reopened?